# emu8086 doesn't work (NI DataSocket 19.0)

Tags: windows, assembly, emu8086

when I open emu8086 after installing it, this message about NI DataSocket 19.0 appears and emu8086 refuses to open. Anyone knows why this appears?

[image]

Comment: Please don't show errors just as images, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is that emu8086 tries to find a file called DataSocket.msi. What you need to do is to go to your file Explorer, type in the Search bar **DataSocket.msi** and then, when the computer finds the file for you, click right on the file. Choose properties and then copy the location of the file and go back to message shown to you in emu8086. Paste the location address of DataSocket.msi in "Use source", then press Ok. This should solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GE8L.png)